# C# Use HttpContext.Current.Request Cannot get QueryString e when requested on mobile browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

This is my public method(APIUtility)

```
public static string GetRequestData(string key, string defaultVal)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current != null && HttpContext.Current.Request != null)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.Request[key] == null || HttpContext.Current.Request[key].Trim() == "" ? defaultVal : HttpContext.Current.Request[key].Trim();
    }
    else
    {
        return defaultVal;
    }
}
```

Have the html used javascript `location.href(aa.json?key=value&key1=value1....)` go to url my class funtion

In the Function aa used `string getUrlValue = APIUtility.GetRequestData(key name)` get Querystring.

The user uses the phone browser (OppoBrowser or safari..) to jump to the server function through my html page 
Unable to get querystring is empty, but if using a computer is normal.

Hope you can understand what I want to express.

Comment: doesnt matter what browser you use it will translate to raw HTTP request at the end of the day. What's the value of `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url`

Comment: I check the log HttpContext.Current.Request.Url is complete, but I can't get it with request[value], the   request[value] is null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString`

```
public static string GetRequestData( string key, string defaultVal ) {
    try {
        var ctx = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
        var value = ctx.Request.QueryString[key];
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? defaultVal : value;
    } catch {
        return defaultVal;
    }
}
```

[Learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.querystring?view=netframework-4.7.2)